# if i add font-weight to a paragraph, the text inside <span> changes to. what is the reason? added the code

Tags: html, css

```css
.tweet {
  width: 600px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.twitter-handle {
  color: rgb(29, 155, 240);
}
```

```html
<p class="tweet">
  As a web developer, you'll want to make your projects easy to use and navigate around.
</p>

<p class="tweet">
  Here <span class="twitter-handle">@chp_it</span> outlines the top skills new developers should have.
</p>
```

tried to bold the tweet text, instead the code gets applied for the  @chp_it tag too.

Comment: *the text inside <span> changes to.*  Changes to what?

Comment: A lot of CSS is naturally inherited, if you don't want the span to inherit its parent's font weight, you will need to explicitly tell it to use another weight.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're styling everything in the `<p>` element, and the `<span>` is in the `<p>` element.

If you want a specific style for the `<span>`, you can give it style rules just like you do for the `<p>` element.  For example, to reset the `font-weight`:

```css
.tweet {
  width: 600px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.twitter-handle {
  color: rgb(29, 155, 240);
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<p class="tweet">
  As a web developer, you'll want to make your projects easy to use and navigate around.
</p>

<p class="tweet">
  Here <span class="twitter-handle">@chp_it</span> outlines the top skills new developers should have.
</p>
```